# Jenkins / Slack : check if message has been send after using slackSend()

Tags: jenkins, groovy, slack

Hay,

I want to check if my Slack Message has been send to he chat. I can't find any kind of result of 
slackSend() which i can use for that.

I want to do sth like that in my Groovy Scipt:

```
result = slackSend(color: ..., message: ...)
if(result.hasSend()){
 //send sth in log
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Usually if some operation inside the pipeline hasn't succeeded, the whole build is aborted. This is to say, in the line next to `slackSend()` you can assume that `slackSend` has succeeded.

Comment: @MaratC thanks for your answer. I want to print a „Send to Slack successfull“ and if i always send that, it will send even if nothing has send to slack(e.g. if the channel is non-existing), thats my Problem.

Comment: In that case, just wrap the slackSend line in try catch, send success to logs in try after slackSend line and send failure to logs in catch block.

Comment: @RahulSharma thanks thats what i needed. It was very obvious ^^ thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In that case, just wrap the slackSend line in try catch, send success
>   to logs in try after slackSend line and send failure to logs in catch
>   block. – Rahul Sharma